# VPN's IP of remote machine connected to that VPN

Tags: ssh, ip, remote-access, vpn, local-network

I would like to connect the remote machine to my local VPN and then ssh to that remote machine from the other machines in my local network.

Is this possible? Will the remote machine get new IP which will be visible in my local network? Do I need to configure anything manually?

I'm using FortiClient for VPN.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I have connected the remote machine to VPN, but when I list all IP's in my network, I don't see new IP for this machine.

And I lost any connection with the remote machine which is on AWS since the ssh is not working anymore due to routing changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is absolutely possible. Try Following steps

- 1-Deploy VPN and assign the ipranges in DHCP public or private
- 2-Make Sure to turn off the firewall for vpn server for now
- 3-Turn off the Clients Firewall
- 4-Connect to VPN
- 5-If your connection loose try to see the client's IP from server
  side and try to take SSH
- 6-Take ssh from your server
- 7- Ping the server from other local machines
- 8-Then enable the server side firewall and see the effect if ssh is
  still possible if not make a rule for specific port for ssh